# Where should the ball touch the foot when juggling in football?

Tags: football, technique, training

To be better in juggling a football, I need to have the ball touch a specific area of my foot, where is it?

Is it the middle of somewhere between instep and toes? or somewhere else like the following?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the instep when you're still learning it. This way it is easier to control the ball. Also make sure to keep your foot in the correct position. Most mistakes come from bad foot positioning, although it is pretty simple. Just keep the foot in the same position as if you were still standing. Then move your leg, not your foot.

[image]

Also watching videos of pros doing it is a good idea. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_s2GrO_CNTE) Marcelo does a few tricks and due to his great techniques you can easily learn from his movements.

Comment: Thank you. when the ball bounces off my foot, should I keep my foot still or relaxed?

Comment: For better accuracy it's better to keep it still. Relaxed feet take more practice.