# How can I correct my juggling?

Tags: football, technique, training

While practicing juggling I discovered two things:

- I am *currently* horrible at juggling
- The ball seems to have a backspin when I hit it

The two seem related.

Let me explain:

When juggling, the ball seems to hit a place on my foot right below my laces. I try to keep my foot firm and myself in a stationary position -- yet the ball spins off of it and back towards me - usually bouncing off my shins. Maybe my foot or toes are curling upwards?

**What is the root of the problem here and what would be the most effective way to combat it?**

---

I have looked at [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/24874/where-should-the-ball-touch-the-foot-when-juggling-in-football), and it was helpful, but I do not think mine is a duplicate, as that question asks what the best way to do this skill is, while I am asking about addressing a particular problem I have encountered.

Comment: Some backspin is normal and you can counter this by getting used to it. If it spins too much you hit the ball at the wrong place. (Probably because you have the ball too far away from your body, which gives you a bad angle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have talked to some friends and showed them my juggling, and most of them think that I am juggling on or right above my toes.

If I am indeed juggling with my toes, I could understand the backspin because it would hit the tip of my foot and curl back toward or away from me. This is not controlled at all and doesn't get me very many juggles.

They suggested practicing juggling the ball off the proper area of my foot by resorting to the simple method of dropping the ball, juggling one or two times, and then catching it - this time with the proper area of the foot (right below the laces) to retrain myself before trying to regularly juggle.

Hopefully this works.